# vsftp not able to login from localhost

Tags: centos7, vsftpd

I have setup `vsftpd` on a centos-7. There are simple and straight forward tutorials for that. However, not only from outside of the server, even from the `localhost`, I am not able to login via ftp.

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/vsftpd/ftpusers
# Users that are not allowed to login via ftp
root
mahmood
bin
daemon
adm
lp
sync
shutdown
halt
mail
news
uucp
operator
games
nobody
[root@localhost ~]# ftp mahmood@localhost
ftp: mahmood@localhost: Name or service not known
ftp> quit

[root@localhost ~]# ftp localhost
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost (::1).
220 (vsFTPd 3.0.2)
Name (localhost:root): root
530 Permission denied.
Login failed.
ftp> quit
221 Goodbye.
```

Any idea about that?

Comment: If you want to log on as user mahmood then `mahmood@localhost` is probably not a valid syntax for your FTP client, check `man ftp` how to specify the username on the commandline

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, it looks like you can **connect** to the FTP server, you just can't login. There's a significant difference.

That looks like correct behaviour. Remember that the `ftpusers` file lists the accounts which are **not allowed** to login to the FTP server (as it says in the comment at the top).

Either take the account that you want to use out of that file or use another account.